# Determining Array sizes at different time

Tags: arrays, dynamic, static, heap-memory, bounds

[image]
Array sizes at different stages. How would bounds checking be described and allocation and representation checking. Consider both one and multidimensional array.

Comment: You know they're not gonna ask you to answer questions that aren't already solved online?

Comment: Did you seriously post something directly out of a textbook assignment?

Comment: See: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/55075)